# Let the vertices of the graph G be the numbers 1, 2, ..., 100, a. Determine χ(G), the chromatic number of the graph G

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics

Let the vertices of the graph G be the numbers 1, 2, ..., 100, and two (different) vertices be adjacent if and only if at least one of **2, 3, or 5 is a common divisor** of the respective numbers. Determine *χ(G)*, the chromatic number of the graph G.

I tried to solve and got that all even numbers i.e 2,4,6,...,100 form a clique of size 50.
And that all prime numbers are isolated so they do not matter in coloring. But I cannot show
chromatic number is 50. Any suggestions?

Comment: All even numbers form a clique, as they have $2$ as a common divisor. You will need at least $51$ colors.

Comment: HOW? Number of even numbers are 50 not 51

Comment: In addition to the 25 prime numbers, there are 4 other isolated vertices: 1, 49, 77, 91.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint 1:

> Show that the graph is $50$-partite.

Hint 2:

> Each partite set contains exactly two elements.

Full Solution:

> For colors $c_1,\dotsc,c_{50}$, assign color $c_i$ to numbers $2i-1$ and $2i$. Note that no two consecutive numbers can have a common divisor other than $1$.

Comment: Very smart. Thank you